# Why favicon not working instead of using question mark in the end after deploying on github pages

Tags: html, favicon, ico

This is what I used but not working after deployed on github pages it still not working with out without question mark. Why?

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/favicon1.ico?">
```

Comment: this issue i guess regarding your path because on local static directory works fine but for GitHub pages server we need to use relational path

Comment: Or after deploy have to tries hard refresh your website?

Comment: Can you please help me :- https://github.com/mohit421/Portfolio

Comment: Yes, please go through with below mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Simplay user this `href="./img/favicon1.ico?"` path/href insted `href="/img/favicon1.ico?"` I just add `'.'` infront of `'/img'`.